# git error "Cannot rewrite branch(es) with a dirty working directory"

Tags: git

`"Cannot rewrite branch(es) with a dirty working directory".`

I am new to Git - I tried *googling* for an answer to no avail.

What does this error mean? What should/can I do?

Comment: it is my first git repo and I had committed something not belonging... had to correct it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I'm experienced with git.  If I do `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter somedir -- --all` I end up with my whole repo processed but if I do `git filter-branch --tree-filter `rm somefile` -- --all` it quits after processing the first branch with the error mentioned above.  Why does `filter-branch` save the state of `--subdirectory-filter` but stop if `--tree-filter` changes the directory?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A dirty working directory means you have uncommitted changes to your branch.  You can either commit them or stash them.  To stash just use:

```
git stash
```

And use this to bring your changes back

```
git stash apply
```

Comment: Note that you might actually not have a dirty working directory: there's a bug in git prior to 1.7.7.1 which means git doesn't refresh its internal indexes when running `filter-branch`. So try running these two commands anyway - unless anyone knows of a less hacky way to force index refresh. (More discussion of this on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463963/git-filter-branch-says-working-tree-is-dirty-when-it-is-not) .)

Comment: From a comment added at the link above: `git update-index -q --ignore-submodules --refresh` should update the index!

Comment: You can use `git stash pop` to apply the last stashed changes and remove them from the stash list. `apply` will apply the changes but a `git stash list` still shows the stashed changes.