# Git filter-branch says working tree is dirty when it is not

Tags: git, command-line

I'm trying to rewrite my history in my git repository because I need to remove a file that contains restricted information.

This is what happens:

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch FILE' master
Cannot rewrite branch(es) with a dirty working directory.
```

So I think "that's weird, I'm pretty sure I don't have uncommitted changes", and I run:

```
$ git status -u
# On branch master
nothing to commit (use -u to show untracked files)
```

What is going on here? Does anyone have an idea for what could be happening? There are submodules in this repository.

#### Submodule Staging Info

I have 18 submodules (all Vim plugins), and here are their statuses. Thought this might be useful info.

```
$ for i in $(ls); do cd $i; git status -u; cd ..; done;
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

#### Other info

```
$ git diff-files --ignore-submodules --quiet
$ echo $?
1
$ git diff-index --cached --quiet HEAD --
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: did you try `filter-branch` again _after_ running `git status`? Maybe only the timestamp of a file changed and `filter-branch` doesn't check for that to remove the dirty flag

Comment: Yep, I did. Same result.

Comment: then it's most likely due to the submodules, with which I don't have any experience, sorry

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not. I've run git status in all of the submodules as well--all have clean working directories.

Comment: What does `git status -u` show? Also have you tried removing any untracked files and or doing this on a completely new clone?

Comment: @Dan: that's not convincing. You'd have to try _without_ the submodules to get any kind of definitive result. Oh, and file a bug if the submodules prevent the filter-branch :)

Comment: The command you pasted does not give the submodule status, but the same supermodule status several times. Please check the exit status of the following commands:
"git diff-files --ignore-submodules --quiet",
 "git diff-index --cached --quiet HEAD --"

Comment: @drizzd oops!! updating with the correct output.

Comment: @X-Istence `git status -u` shows the same output.

Comment: @drizzd Just updated with the exit statuses you requested.

Comment: Ok, then the output of "git diff-files --ignore-submodules" should be non-empty and that is the reason why filter-branch refuses to run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is mostly a guess, but the error may be caused by a bug that was [fixed](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commitdiff;h=5347a50fec066845e5dfa34a53cbec1ea347641d) in git v1.7.7.1 (which was released after your original post).  From the commit message:

> Filter-branch already requires that we have a clean work tree before starting.  However, it failed to refresh the index before checking, which means it could be wrong in the case of stat-dirtiness.

Comment: Prior to 1.7.7.1 (I have 1.7.0.4) you'll presumably need to force git to refresh the index. I've found that you can do this by running `git stash` and then `git stash apply`, as if you _did_ have a dirty working dir (taken from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030477/git-error-cannot-rewrite-branches-with-a-dirty-working-directory) ). Git will complain, but filter-branch should then work. If anyone has a less hacky method then please mention it here!

Comment: @J-P:  The fix linked in my answer causes `git filter-branch` to run the following to refresh the index:  `git update-index -q --ignore-submodules --refresh`

Comment: Switching from 1.7.1 to 1.8.3.4 fixed this issue for me.

Comment: I had this issue when trying to split a directory into a separate repo via