# git author rename not working

Tags: git, github

I've got a git repository where I'm the only committer, so far, and that has already been published on github. I found that a few commits, being done from a different computer, has the wrong author information. My idea was to remove the repository from github, rewrite history and republish it as new.
For such purpose I've created a simple script:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
            GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Author Name";
            GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Author Name";
            GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="email";
            GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="email";
            git commit-tree "$@";

    ' HEAD
```

which should rename all commits. The problem is that git replies with

```
Cannot rewrite branch(es) with a dirty working directory.
```

but a git status provides me

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Any idea about what am I missing? Any suggestion on how to rename all commits without loosing the history will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Git are you using? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9246622/6309

Comment: try to issue a `git reset --hard` to clean the Working tree.

Comment: Seems that a reset fixed the problem. I was already running an updated git version (1.7.2.5).

Comment: You also have to export those environment variables

Comment: You don't need to remove and re-add repository at GitHub. Just `git push --force`

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting untracked files in your working directory by running `git clean -dxf`.

Also, you'll need to export those variables in your commit-filter.  If you don't, Git won't see them so they won't alter Git's default behavior.